# Ao acessar um *.php levar para autostart.php?url=*.php

Tags: php, apache, htaccess, url

Olá,

Estou com um problema, preciso que ao acessar um arquivo qualquer `.php`, ele direcione para `autostart.php?url=*.php`

Explicação:

No `autostart.php` ele da include em um arquivo e após ele dá include na pagina que está no `GET`.

Fiz isso com HTACCESS, mais não consegui fazer funcionar como queria.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule .*\.(php)$ autostart.php?url=$1 [R,NC,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Não compensa usar o "autoinclude" do próprio PHP então? Se tiver acesso a essa configuração, pode usar [auto_prepend_file e auto_append_file](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.auto_prepend_file).

Comment: Mais tipo, teria que editar o php.ini, preciso de uma solução no próprio código-fonte, já que preciso usar diversas vezes.

Comment: Na verdade, não seria `^(*.)\.php)$ autostart.php?url=$1`? Pois o $1 pegaria o grupo do regex retornado na primeira expressão (e no seu caso esse grupo seria sempre o "php"). Espero que eu não tenha falado besteira, rsrsrsrs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*\.php)$ autostart.php?url=$1 [R,NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Não acho que seja uma boa ideia usar este método para fazer include dos arquivos. Se a opção [allow_url_include](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-include) do php estiver ativada você acaba de abrir uma brecha gigantesca no seu sistema que vai permitir que qualquer um injete e execute um script php no seu servidor.

Se você for realmente fazer dessa forma ***não dê include no parâmetro `url` diretamente*** sem fazer antes uma validação para ver se o arquivo pode ser realmente incluído no seu script.;

Comment: Obrigado por resolver meu problema, o autostart ele valida com is_file(). Grato pelas dicas.